# is it possible to use .cer file to server website without private key?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, https

Today i imported a certificate with mmc ( certlm.msc ) without need of any private and everything is working just fine.
my question is that doesn't IIS need private key to serve a https website ? How this works ?
edti : How can i import private key into windows ( i have private key in a text file along with site and ca certificate

Comment: `doesn't IIS need private key to serve a https website?` Yes it does, but certlm does not bind a certificate to a website.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so can i import private key in windows because i only have .pem file that has four sections 1) CSR 2) Private key 3,4) site and ca certificates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows wants the private key and the certificate combined into a single PKCS#12 file. You can create one with a command like this:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out filename.p12 -inkey filename.key -in filename.cer

Or if you need to include intermediate certificates, place them all into a file (in this example, root.crt) and bundle this way:

openssl pkcs12 -export -in input.crt -inkey input.key -certfile root.crt -out bundle.p12

Once you have created this .p12 file move it over to the Windows machine and import it into the 'Certificates' snap-in within your MMC. DO NOT just click on the certificate in Explorer to start the import wizard – this will import the certificate into the personal store of the user you're logged in as, which will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer and explanation works like a charm,